# All 2-regular graphs with the same number of vertices are isomorphic to each other.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I need to prove or disprove that all 2-regular graphs with the same number of vertices are isomorphic to each other. I've tried to come up with a counter example but it seems wrong and forced to me. Below you can see two edgelists for two graphs who are both 2-regular but not isomorphic to each other. 
$ E_{1} := \{(a,b),(b,c),(c,d),(d,e),(e,f),(f,g),(g,a) \}$
$ E_{2} := \{(a,b),(b,c),(c,a),(d,e),(e,f),(f,g),(g,d) \}$

is the second edgelist still a graph or two distinct graphs?

In general, how do I proceed on proofs like this? always try to find a counter example or how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right, the first is a connected graph, the second is a graph
that isn't connected.

What is true is that all **connected** $2$-regular graphs with $n$ vertices
are isomorphic, being $n$-cycle graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Your counterexample is correct, because there was no condition about connectivity.

Comment: why does it make sense to have graphs who have two completely disjoint sets of vertices? Are they perhaps still considered as one since they both are on the same set?

Comment: I guess you should read about [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) to understand graphs better.